# returning null from CompletableFuture exceptionally block in Kotlin for a non-null returning method

Tags: kotlin, completable-future

I'm surprised the following Kotlin code compiles. If the exception block is hit, I return null, and the signature of the method does not allow null return values. Why does the compiler allow this?

```
suspend fun getRandomString(): String {
    return httpClient.sendAsync(HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create((baseUrl + "/getRandomString")).normalize())
            .build(), BodyHandlers.ofString()).thenApply {
                       it.body().toUpperCase()
            }.exceptionally {
                  log.error("could not retrieve a random string from the magical endpoint due to exception {}", it)
                  null
             }.await()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Disregard! This is due to CompletableFuture returning a "String!", i.e, a platform type. String! means (String or String?), so the compiler lets it slide.

Comment: The best approach here would be to delete your post, instead of making it a documented confession.